# SW-Architecture - Caching between service- and persistence layer

Tags: caching, architecture, filesystems

I'm developing a file system which encapsulates access to an Amazon S3 bucket using the fuse library and jnr-fuse (https://github.com/SerCeMan/jnr-fuse) as a java binding.

I have a first version working and am currently doing some code-cleanup and refactoring work, trying to get everything into a proper multi-layered architecture.

So far I have roughly the following:

- Frontend: This is the actual implementation of the FuseFileSystem interface from jnr-fuse. It has some dependencies to jnr (native) types and the methods are the java equivalents of fuse's c-functions.
- Service Layer: One interface that has "non-native-dependent" versions of all the file-system methods from the frontend layer, but no dependencies to jnr or fuse whatsoever. The idea is that this could be used in other contexts as well (e.g. as the core component of an implementation of the java.nio.FileSystem-API for S3 or any other scenario where someone would need an API making S3 accessible in a "filesystem-ish" fashion but not want to do that via fuse and therefore not want all the jnr dependencies)

Where I'm currently struggling is the persistence layer: As all communication with S3 is actually done via http, I'm doing some fair amount of caching to reduce traffic and increase performance.
The question is where that caching would best fit..

Obviously the actual DAOs should not be polluted with any kind of caching/locking logic - they should only handle the actual access to the data (i.e. doing the http calls against S3).
On the other hand, also the service layer shouldn't really be concerned with caching (in case the persistence layer and with it the caching requirements change), so I was thinking of doing one of the following:

1. Use a "doubled" persistence layer: Each DAO is implemented twice: One version that holds a cache and serves data out of it's cache. If an object is not in the cache, we delegate to the second DAO which actually fetches the object (which is then added to the cache)
2. Introduce a separate "cache" layer with slightly different interfaces than the actual persistence layer that handles all caching requirements and delegates to the persistence layer as necessary.

Version 1 would be the cleaner one from the service-layer point of view - there wouldn't be any difference between using a cache and not using it because all calls to the persistence layer would go against the same interface. On the other hand it would also transfer all the logic concerning the state or "lifecycle" of a file (open -> read/write -> close) to the persistence layer.
Version 2 would manage the lifecycle of the file inside the "cache" layer, which I think would make the whole thing easier to understand for anyone new to the code. On the other hand it also assumes that there will *always* be a cache layer (which is probably true).

Are there any other pros and cons to the above approaches from a design point of view or is there any pattern out there which addresses this kind of problem?

Right now I'd rather go with option 2 but it'd be really interesting to hear some opinions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why are you opposed to caching in the DAO?  This has always been the perfect place for me to cache.  It is a data access concern, and thus goes into the data access layer.  A couple of times I've used various AOP implementations for convenience, but 90% of the time, i'm implementing caching logic inside the DAO.

The cache itself does not live in the DAO, it is usually it's own interface, so I can swap between implementations (in-memory, on-disk, etc).

I have also had some luck when using Apache HTTP client's own built-in caching.  It allows you to respect HTTP cache semantics, or override it with custom logic.

Comment: I still have my doubts because of the choreography: When a file is read by another process it's opened, then read, then closed after reading is finished. At the moment open is called the file is already loaded into the cache. However, for a "pure" DAO an "open" operation doesn't really make sense (unless it has a cache) - the same goes for closing something, which was the reason I was thinking about decoupling that. But you're right, the data access layer is probably still the best fit - I just have to figure out the details ;)